# Running a Modular GWT in DevMode

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I recently modified changed my GWT app from having a single project into a modular project using the maven archetype modular-webapp (https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes). While everything works well when using the SuperDevMode, I can't get the old DevMode working with the new structure. I'd like to use the project with the old DevMode again, because I feel more familiar with the debugging in eclipse.

I follow the steps provided at the howto for the modular-webapp archetype:

1. mvn clean install -Dgwt.compiler.skip
2. In one terminal window: cd *-client && mvn gwt:run -Ddev
3. In another terminal window: mvn tomcat7:run -Ddev

All steps seem to succeed, though there i a warning in step 2:

```
[WARNING] Your POM <build><outputdirectory> does not match your hosted webapp WEB-INF/classes folder for GWT Hosted browser to see your classes.
```

But when I open the browser from the GWT window, I just get a blank page. So maybe there's something wrong with gwt-maven-plugin configuration:

```
<properties>
    <gwt.genParam>false</gwt.genParam>
    <!-- keep in sync with *-server -->
    <runTarget>http://localhost:8080</runTarget>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <module>testproject.Project</module>
                <strict>true</strict>
                <genParam>${gwt.genParam}</genParam>
                <noserver>true</noserver>
                <runTarget>${runTarget}</runTarget>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Is there any error in the browser dev tools? (does it finds the nocache.js to begin with?)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, you were right.

Comment: BTW, the `[WARNING] Your POM <build><outputdirectory> does not match your hosted webapp WEB-INF/classes folder for GWT Hosted browser to see your classes.` comes from the gwt-maven-plugin and tells you that DevMode would not see your server-side classes if they ever changed, but you don't care as DevMode only runs the client side of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser couldn't find the nocache.js, which was caused by a typo in the argument for the maven profile. I used -PDev instead of -Pdev.